# Write a csv file after scraping data from reddit

Tags: python, export-to-csv, reddit

I am new to coding and I am not being able to write a CSV file with the data I scraped from Reddit.

First, I scraped data using the pushshift API, which returned the results in a list format like the following image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff4ZI.jpg)

I want to write that data to a CVS file to run a content analysis in R. With each line (0000, 00001, etc) as a row. However, I have not been able to run a code that organizes each parameter in a column. For instance, I want the columns to be submissions.author, submissions.num_comments, submissions.title, to name a few.

I ran this piece of code but the results are not exactly what I'm looking for

```
import csv
 with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
      for row in lastest_submissions:
        row_text = ','.join(row) + '\n'  
        f.write(row_text)
```

The outcome looks like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkpLE.png)

What I would like is that the name of the parameter is the header and the parameter answer is the content in each cell. For example, for parameter 'author':'bl00d', the header would be author and the content in the cell would be bl00d (for the line 0000).

I appreciate the help and hints I could get. Also, let me know if I should provide the complete code

Comment: It's not neccesary to open the csv twice.
Also, I don't see where you add the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case as you already have the data in the form of list of dictionaries I think you may wanna try using *csv.Dictwriter()*

A sample code piece:

```py
import csv
lstdc = [{'name':'Jack', 'age': 26}, 
        {'name':'John', 'age': 27},
        {'name':'Lisa', 'age': 36},
        {'name':'Adam', 'age': 16}]

fieldNames = list((lstdc[0]).keys())

with open('list_of_dict_to_csv.csv','w', newline='\n') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldNames)
    writer.writeheader()
    for val in lstdc:
        writer.writerow(val)
```

you can replace the *lstdc* with *latest_submissions* and **list_of_dict_to_csv.csv** with **my_file.csv**

Replacing the iteration of list dictionaries with built in writerows()

```py
with open('list_of_dict_to_csv.csv','w', newline='\n') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldNames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(lstdc)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This should suffice:

```
with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    headers = lastest_submissions[0].keys()
    writer.writerow(headers)

    with open('my_file.csv', 'w') as f:
        for row in lastest_submissions:
            writer.writerow(row.values())
```